# Cant manage to extract a field using JQ in a json file

Tags: jq

I've been searching for a solution on this forever but still haven't managed to do it.

I'm trying to get the long number field (see below) and ommit everything else but fail to do so.

This is the JSON file contents:

```
{
    "jsonProfile": {
        "version": "1.0",
        "format": 1
    },
    "authenticationDatabase": {
        "JQ_Newb": {
            "username": "JQ_Newb",
            "profiles": {
                "12345678901234567890123456789012": {
                    "displayName": "JQ_Newb"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my filter:

```
.authenticationDatabase|.[]|.profiles
```

And this is the result:

```
{
  "12345678901234567890123456789012": {
    "displayName": "JQ_Newb"
  }
}
```

Thanks for helping, Stackoverflow people!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will extract all key names from `.authenticationDatabase.JQ_Newb.profiles` :

```
jq -r '.authenticationDatabase.JQ_Newb.profiles | to_entries[] | .key' data.json
```

In case you have multiple keys in `.authenticationDatabase.JQ_Newb.profiles`, it will give :

```
12345678901234567890123456789012
12345678901234567890123456789013
```

To get the values under all keys in `.authenticationDatabase.JQ_Newb.profiles` :

```
jq -r '.authenticationDatabase.JQ_Newb.profiles | to_entries[] | .value ' data.json
```

Comment: That did the trick for me (but only at jqplay.org)! at CMD JQ-win32 (1.5) crashes when passing ".authenticationDatabase.JQ_Newb.profiles | to_entries[] | .key " to it. So it works, but somehow not in the environment i'm using it (cmd/batch). Because of this unexpected behaviour I'm not sure if i should mark your answer as solution. It DOES help me in the right direction, i'm just wondering what causes JQ to crash.

Comment: Does the crash happen when you only request the first part jq -r "authenticationDatabase.JQ_Newb.profiles" file.json, test removing the `-r`,  just to try to isolate the issue

Comment: I hope i'm doing this right (it seems to work fine this way): TYPE data.json | jq-win32 -r ".authenticationDatabase.JQ_Newb.profiles | to_entries[] | .key" (is the whitespace character needed in ".key "?). Marked as Solved! Thank you so much Bertrand Martel! :-)

Comment: There is no whitespace required between `|` : `.authenticationDatabase.JQ_Newb.profiles|to_entries[]|.key`

Comment: Merci beaucoup! :-)

Answer (score 1):

I had answered you but you were no longer in the channel - it's not very active as you may have noticed ;_;

You've already been given a working solution but here was my answer using `keys`

```
user@host $ jq -r '.authenticationDatabase.JQ_Newb.profiles | keys' jqnewb.json 
[
  "12345678901234567890123456789012"
]
user@host $ jq -r '.authenticationDatabase.JQ_Newb.profiles | keys[]' jqnewb.json 
12345678901234567890123456789012
```

Comment: For real? I didn't notice. Sorry about that and thanks for giving the solution anyway. My earlier attempt on #JQ at IRC wasn't a success (no response there) so i'm REALLY grateful for the great support you guys offer :-)

Comment: Oh sorry for the confusion - I am talking about #JQ :-) You had gone by the time I answered. It's not very active - but there you go. \o/

Comment: No problem! Again, your efforts are greatly appreciated! Have a good one!